# Symbol for quotient field of an integral domain

Tags: soft-question, field-theory

This may be a naive question, but I do feel that there is no standard notation for quotient of an integral domain, say $R$. I often use the notation Quot$(R)$ and other people use qf$(R)$ and yet again some people write Frac$(R)$. I'm not really looking for a standard symbol, but I want to know or guess what many of you are most comfortable with. I prefer to write the notation for which most people feel comfortable with. I hope some can share their preferred notation.

Comment: $Quot(R)$ is the symbol I always used

Comment: I think quotient field is a misleading term (though I know it is being used), because it is not a quotients ring at all. The IMO proper term is "field of fractions" or "fraction field" (because that is what things like $3/4$ are: fractions, not quotients), and $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ seems like a reasonable (and certainly used) notation for them.

Comment: I use $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ (because of the standard rings and modules of fractions’ in Commutative Algebra. QF(R) is not international (a field is not a field in all languages).

Comment: @Bernard could you elaborate "a field is not a field in all languages"?

Comment: In French, it's « un corps » (commutatif); in German, *Körper*; in Spanish: *cuerpo*; in Italian: *campo* (same word) as English; in Greek *Σώμα* (same word as the other languages).